# Returning a negative value before returning positive ones?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, when this code is executed in my game it first returns negative `rb.velocity.y` values before returning positive ones and I can't figure out why. The speed variable is equal to 7 at all times.

I have tried to change the `speed` and `speedModifier` variables without success.

```cs
if (wallGrab && !isDashing)
        {
            rb.gravityScale = 0;

                if (x > .2f || x < -.2f)
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);

                float speedModifier = y > 0 ? .5f : 1;


                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, y * (speed * speedModifier));

            }

        }
        else
        {
            rb.gravityScale = 3;
        }
```

Someone wanted more code, let me explain how it works.
The first if statement check if the player is holding on to a wall, it then sets the gravity to 0. Then it checks if the player is trying to move towards the wall, and then if true sets the y velocity to 0. And then it changes the velocity. The thing is that this code works both for the "slide" function and the climb function of the game. Thus if y > 0 it will climb and if y<0 it will slide down the wall.

Comment: I would like to know what variable y is, and when do you call this code? also did you disable the gravity on your object in the inspector?

Comment: The code is called once the player ”grabs” a wall, Y is the vertical input from the player, and yes, the gravity is set to 0

Comment: is the rb.velocity change at the exact time you turn gravityScale to 0? or only when the input something?

Comment: When the character is grabbing a wall the gravity is constantly 0, so lets say i hold on to the middle of a wall and press the uparrow, i will then first be pushed down a bit and then ascend

Comment: thats weird, ill try to reproduce the issue on my computer with your code when ill be home

Comment: So what if `y < 0` ? Could you add kore code for context?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ONt5GV8.gifv here is an example of what happens if you try to climb (I spam the W key when i continuously go down)

Answer (score 0):

ok so i couldnt really figure out the problem so I just implemented a janky solution;

```cs
if (wallGrab && !isDashing)
        {
            rb.gravityScale = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);


                if (x > .2f || x < -.2f)
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);

                float speedModifier = y > 0 ? .5f : 1;


            if(yRaw < 0)
            {
                climbingDown = true;
                climbingUp = false;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -3.5f);
            }
            else if (yRaw > 0)
            {
                climbingDown = false;
                climbingUp = true;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 3f);
            }
            else
            {
                climbingDown = false;
                climbingUp = false;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            rb.gravityScale = 3;
        }
```

Instead of trying to make everything work with one line i just seperate the different outcomes with the raw Y value (1,0 or -1) and from there have a static movement